# How to fix iTunes/Skype where fonts all show up as boxes after Mountain Lion upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, font

When I login to iTunes or Skype the fonts all show up as boxes.

No fonts were removed on installed; none are disabled and all the normal ones show up. Doesn't happen on any web site; only seems to be locally installed programs.

Uninstalled and reinstalled and programs still don't work.

[Example Image](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/1d110186-9747-4a24-ba2d-bc662728339b/8f84c7a73b0ac5f422c91df60e0c0aae)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have Fonts Caches (or actual Fonts) that are corrupt. I would do the following, to not only clear the caches, but also to verify your Fonts.

**Clearing the font cache** - you have a few options (Onyx is just easier).

1. Use a tool like [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr), which can do this and many other maintenance tasks for you.
2. Manually remove the cache with the command line `atsutil` utility. You basically would do `astutil databases -removeUser` then `sudo astutil databases -remove`, then `astutil server -shutdown`, then `astutil server -ping`. I would recommend restarting after this.
3. Choose from various other utilities like Onyx that clear just the font cache.
4. Some people also recommend clearing out the `/Library/Caches` folder, but I am not sure how well this works. There also used to be some older ways to clear the cache but I cant find them (and I am pretty sure it was tools before Mac OS 10.5).

**Verifying Fonts**

1. Open up Font Book (in `/Applications/`)
2. Select All
3. Go to the File Menu and select `Validate Fonts`.
4. Resolve any issues this may present, but those may be specific to your machine.

[image]

Usually clearing the Font Cache works. I used to see a similar problem all the time with Microsoft Office 2004, and it had its own cache that we even cleared weekly. I haven't seen the Mac OS mess its cache up that often, but when it does, usually a quick fix. I have even seen a reboot sometimes clear it up (in very minor cases).

Answer (score 1):

I think jmlumpkin nailed it with clearing the font cache.

For what it’s worth, there’s a much easier way to clear the font cache for many people that doesn’t involve the Terminal, and that is by using [Safe Boot.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564) Once booted to the login screen, you don’t even need to sign in — simply restart, and use the computer normally.